# Find the function $f(x)$ to which $f_{n}$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis

Show that the sequence of functions $f_{n}$ defined on $[0,1]$ by

$f_{n}(x)= n(1-nx), 0≤x<\frac{1}{n}$
$= 0, \frac{1}{n} ≤ x≤ 1$ converges to a function $f(x)=0$.

My attempt-

For $x \in (0,1]$, $f(x)=0$, as for any $c \in (0,1]$, there exists $m \in N$, such that $1/m <c$

But I didn't understand why does $f_{n}$ converges to $0$, when $x=0$. If we put $x=0$, then $f_{n}(0) = n$.

Where am I wrong$?$

Comment: You are right. $f_n(x)$ converge to $0$ in $(0,1]$ but not at $x = 0$.

Comment: This question only makes sense if you are given a norm on functions $[0,1]\to \mathbb R$.  In the uniform norm you are right.  However the question may have given an alternative norm (most likely $L_2$).

Comment: One possible explanation is a typo in the problem. If instead of the definition above $f_n(x) = x(1-nx)$, then it converges to $0$ for $x > 0$ for the same reason as before, and would converge for $x=0$ because every $f_n(0) = 0$. That is a guess, but it would explain why they are asking you to prove something that is false.

Comment: Maybe the question is printed wrong in the textbook.